# How can I implement this code using Tuple?

Tags: c#, tuples

```
class Program
{
    public static void Print(MethodArguments args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID = " + args.ID.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Name =  " + args.Name);
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MethodArguments arguments = new MethodArguments();
        arguments.ID = 20;
        arguments.Name = "John";
        Print(arguments);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you clarify your question? It's not really clear where you want to use a tuple at the moment. (In general, questions where the body is *just* code aren't very helpful - it's very rare that the question title can give all the relevant information.)

Comment: is the question here "how can I use a tuple in place of declaring a `MethodArguments` type?" - because if so, I think that's begging the question... the first question is "should I ....?", and the answer would be "almost certainly not", and which point "how...?" becomes largely moot

Comment: @morteza.akbarinejad Edith?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    private static void Print((int Id, string Name) args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ID = {args.Id.ToString()}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Name = {args.Name}");
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Print((20, "John"));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is a valid answer, it doesn't respond to [Marc' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56217128/how-can-i-implement-this-code-using-tuple#comment99055034_56217128) to explain why we shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: @DavidG because it's definitely cleaner to just use two separate parameters

Comment: @lionthefox I know that, but the person posting should have explained it.

Comment: @DavidG you are absolutely right, sorry i misunderstood your statement

Comment: Yes I agree, sorry I should have mentioned that. Anyway it makes sense to pass multiple values through a single parameter to a method that accepts only one object. For example you can use a `Tuple<T1,T2,T3>` object as a method argument to `Thread.Start(Object)` to supply the thread's startup routine with three items of data. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)